# How to use lodash to filter array and objects

Tags: javascript, lodash

Is there a better way for me to code this. The current code works, but I am looking for better way to code. Code must use lodash. I figure they may be a way to filter where I don't have to create 2 filters then join it together

```
const overwriteExisting = () => {
    // get data that does not have midiChannl = 5
    const filtered1 = filter(data, function (o) {
      return o.midiChannl !== 5;
    });

    // filter out everything that does not have same midiValue hello2
    const filtered2 = filter(dataWithoutCurrentUUID, function (o) {
      return (
       
        o.midiValue !== 'hello2';
      );
    });

    const joinAll = concat(filtered1, filtered2);
    console.log(joinAll)
}

{
    midiType: 1,
    midiValue: "hello",
    midiChannl: 5
},
{
    midiType: 10,
    midiValue: "hello2",
    midiChannl: 4
},
{
    midiType: 100,
    midiValue: "hello2",
    midiChannl: 4
},
{
    midiType: 1000,
    midiValue: "hello4",
    midiChannl: 4
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Would this work? It is not clear if the filters are applied to the same data array.

```js
const overwriteExisting = () => {
    // get data that does not have midiChannl = 5 and does not have same midiValue hello2
    const filtered = filter(data, o =>
      o.midiChannl !== 5 && o.midiValue !== 'hello2'
    );

    console.log(filtered)
}
```

Comment: tried it but it seem as it is applied to the same object

Comment: It is. Can you add some examples the data arrays and the intended result?